# How can I get records created_by user with role

Tags: laravel, eloquent, role

Hi I have a table "fiches" with the user_id who created the record.
All my users have a role_id.

How can I get all "fiches" where user_id has the role of 'admin' or something else.

```
 User.php
 class User extends Authenticatable{

     public function role()
     {
         return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
     }

     // Fiches of User
     public function fiches()
     {
         return $this->hasMany(Fiche::class);
     }

  }


 Fiche.php
 class Fiche extends Model{

     public function user()
     {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
     }

 }
```

My Query

```
 $fiches = Fiche::whereDay('created_at', '=', date('d'))->where('status', '=', 'A Ecouter')->pluck('id')->count();
```

Fiches table (id, user_id, name, status, created_at)

Users table (id, role_id, name, created_at)

I want to have the Fiches that was created by role == Admin

Comment: add code and your tables

Comment: By creating an SQL query that fetches this data.

Comment: @J.Doe I edited my code.

Comment: @Jerodev I want to use eloquent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use whereHas with nested relationship. Assuming your `roles` table has column `type` the code will look like:

```php
$fiches = Fiche::whereHas('user.role', function ($query) {
    $query->where('type', 'admin');
})->get();
```

This query will retrieve all *fiches* that have *users* with *role* that has column 'type' of value 'admin'.

**Edit:**

For your specific case you provided in the comment the query should look like this:

```php
$fichesAEcouterJours = Fiche::whereDay('created_at', '=', date('d'))
    ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('status', '=', 'A Ecouter')
            ->orWhere('status', '=', 'A Reporter');
    })
    ->whereHas('user.role', function($query){ 
        $query->where('name', 'agent'); 
    })
    ->count();
```

Or you can use `->whereIn('status', ['A Ecouter', 'A Reporter'])` instead. Note that there is no need to call `->get()` before `->count()` in this case - it's faster to let Eloquent generate `SELECT COUNT` query than it is to `->get()` collection  of all rows and call `->count()` of that collection.

Comment: $fichesAEcouterJours = Fiche::whereDay('created_at', '=', date('d'))->where('status', '=', 'A Ecouter')->orWhere('status','=','A Reporter')->whereHas('user.role', function($query){
                $query->where('name', 'agent');
})->get()->count();

But it steels to show me all the records

Comment: The problem is probably with `->orWhere()` being by itself, you need to group your status conditions. Check the edit for my answer.